# How to trigger a space key event with keycode

Tags: javascript

I am trying to trigger space key with keycode in JavaScript. I will be sending voice command with space and it should trigger a space event with a keycode.

This is what I have done so far

```
if(firstword =="space"){
  const ev = {
     type: 'space',
    keyCode: 32 
}
editor.triggerOnKeyDown(ev);
```

The code works perfectly if I use enter or other keycode but not working for space, any idea?

Comment: probably because you are declaring const under the if condition, since it's a block scoped.. you won't be able to access it outside of the if condition

Comment: There is no event type named "space". That would not work with "enter", so look at the code that's working and you'll likely find that the type is "keydown", or "keyup".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
const ev = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':32,'which':32});
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 0):

Ty to create `addEventListener` for space

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
       alert('Space pressed');
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: The OP is trying to *trigger* an event, not capture it.